# Why my Recycler view selecting wrong items along with exactly selected items that are clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Why my Recycler view selecting wrong items along with exactly selected  items that are clicked ?** 
[Image To Show Recycler View Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c48P9.png)

I want to place RecyclerView in a pop up activity started on click event and RecycleView should change the background of selected items from view. I have used  following code  for Activity to make it pops up

**Pop Up Activity code**

```
  DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float width=metrics.widthPixels*8/10;
        float  height=metrics.heightPixels*6/10;
        getWindow().setLayout((int)width, (int) height);
```

The code for  **My Recycler View Adapter** is as follows

```
    public class PopUp extends Activity {
    public  int counter=0;
    private int mItemSelected=-1;
    public List<student> students=new ArrayList<student>();
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //to set content view for that activity
         setContentView(R.layout.popup);
        //end of the setting the layout for the activity

        //this is mechanism to calculate the width and height of the screen
        DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float width=metrics.widthPixels*8/10;
        float  height=metrics.heightPixels*6/10;
        getWindow().setLayout((int)width, (int) height);
        //end of the mechanism

        //the method to populate the list
        populateList();
        //end of the method

        //now creating the recycler view
           recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager
     LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(students);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //end of the recycler view

    }

    //this is event for the ok button
     public void Ok(View view){

     }
    //end of the ok button for the pop activity

    //this is event for the button  named as cancel
    public void Cancel(View view){

    }
    //end of the cancel button event

    //this is method for printing line
     public void PrintLine(String line){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),line,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    //end of the method



    //this method to populate the ArrayList
      public void populateList(){
          String name="Mashhood Qadeer Bhatti";
          String address="Sammundri Faisalabad";
          boolean status=false;
          for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
              students.add(new student(name+"\t"+i,address,status));
          }
      }
    //end of the method


    //this is section for recycler adapter
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<student> values;
                //this is constructor
                public MyAdapter(List<student> myDataset) {
                    values = myDataset;
                }

        //end of the constructor

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.getContext());
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                 holder.name.setText(values.get(position).getName().toString());
                 holder.address.setText(values.get(position).getAddress().toString());
                 holder.status.setSelected(values.get(position).getSelction());
                 holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                      if(mItemSelected==position){
                          v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.im));
                          PrintLine("The position matched"+position);
                          values.get(position).setSelction(!values.get(position).getSelction());
                          holder.status.setChecked(values.get(position).getSelction());
                      }
                     }
                 });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        //there will be view holder
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // each data item is just a string in this case
            public TextView name;
            public TextView address;
            public View layout;
            public RadioButton status;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                 super(v);
                 layout = v;
                 name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                 address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
                 status=(RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
              layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mItemSelected=getAdapterPosition();
                    }
                });
                /*  v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                mItemSelected=getAdapterPosition();
                                PrintLine("This is position for the"+getAdapterPosition());
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                values.get(mItemSelected).setSelction(!values.get(mItemSelected).getSelction());
                      }
                  });*/

            }
        }

        //end of the view holder


}
//end of that section
}
```

Comment: User holder.getAdapterPosition() rather than position provided.

Comment: Sir forgive me if I write any thing wrong since I am in early stage of learning.Sir I have used holder to get my ui widgets for example I have a radio button named as status in my ViewAdapter so I want to set radio to be as checked when clicked that is why I am using holder.status.setSelected(); and then give  inverted boolean value to it just for toggle functionality to show be selected or not selected. Sir! if use holder.getAdapterPosition() it will give me id of adapter then how to change the background of it .

Comment: there are two positions which the holder gives us one is the int position in onBindViewHolderMethod which is the position on the visible screen. Another is holder.getAdapterPosition() which is the actual position of the item. So i would suggest you to use the second one.

Comment: Sir as suggested by you and  Sir Anonymous I have placed the obtained position in my global  class field . But I do not know why my recycler view show  [7] indexed position as selected on selecting the item at position [0] I mean it start to show one wrong item to be selected with exact one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recycler view recycles the view in OnBindViewHolder.So when items are clicked it gets reflected in some other positions.To solve this.

create a global variable to store the clicked position.

```
private int mItemSelected = -1;
```

Then inside viewholder add the clickListener and onClick store the position of the clicked item.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
// each data item is just a string in this case
public TextView name;
public TextView address;
public View layout;
public RadioButton status;

public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    layout = v;
    name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
    status = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mItemSelected = getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
  }
}
```

And in
inside OnBindViewHolder,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.name.setText(values.get(position).getName().toString());
    holder.address.setText(values.get(position).getAddress().toString());
    holder.status.setSelected(values.get(position).getSelction());

    if(mItemSelected==position){
        holder.status.setChecked(true)‌;
        v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.im));
    }else{
        holder.status.setChecked(false)‌;
        v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(unselected Item));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir ! selection and changing the background is working but Sir my recyclerView start to select one wrong item with exact on when I select first item at position [0] then it automatically select [7] in addition.Sir When I try this in my previous code it does the same as the code provided above .And I want to prevent it to select  wrong items that are not selected .

Comment: This code will work..The code that has to be shown should be written inside if condition and code for removing selection should in else part.Post the updated code

Comment: Sir I have tried the code  as conditional structure if(mItemSelected==position) and the position that we get in  overridden method  named as onBindViewHolder but My view shows the 7 item as selected on selecting first one have [0] index that is ridiculous behavior of my AdapterView

Comment: holder.status.setSelected(values.get(position).getSelction()); even this should be inside onBindViewHolder i guess.What is the code for selecting and unselecting?

Comment: Sir I have used code to select and for unselection toggle functionality in my binder function as follows: values.get(position).setSelction(!values.get(position).getSelction());
                        holder.status.setChecked(values.get(position).getSelction());

Comment: Your code is wrong @MashhoodQadeerBhatti. Do like this..On selction i.e inside if add code for selection and in else add code for non selectin..then the code will work.see the updated code.

Comment: Sir the code  I have given above is for Radio button selection and for deselection.That radio button is here to show that list item has been selected.And it toggle behavior is fine but problem is with my view that it show one wrong item as selected along with correct one.

Comment: what is view?even background image also you need to add like that..post the updated code and is possible image too.

Comment: Sir you are right .But My request is to prevent holder to select wrong item on click event.

Comment: Did you try my code?It will work for sure.viewholder doesnot give wrong item clicked.

Comment: Sir I have tried your code and same phenomena happened  as with my code.I am also  wonder to see  As we using condition on the mItemSelectedItem then Why it  is doing mistake to select exact item.

Comment: Can you post your updated code again?with my changes

Comment: Yes Sir .I am going to proceed.

Comment: ?You dint proceed with that solution?Dude this will definitely  work :( you should have tired..ok try and let me know.

Comment: Sir I have tried what you said and now I have updated my question by your code.

Comment: main part notifydataSetChanged() is only missing.Then how you expect code to work?

Comment: sir updated the code.Just check once and copy that code

Comment: After checking on Android studio I change my code in question and for more verification if you want I can send you apk

Comment: make all the changes which I said.Your problem will be solved

Comment: Sir ! you are genius . Your line   notifyDataSetChanged(); help me to notify holder to update View that view has been changed but I use  my additional logic to achieve  it according to my scenario(::+  'if(values.get(position).getSelction()) {
                holder.layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.im));
                 }
                 else{
                     holder.layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagee));
                 } '   +:)   and ViewHolder just change  listitem's boolean value to be verified by the Holder

Comment: thanks if my answer helped you upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PopUp extends Activity {
    public  int counter=0;
    private int mItemSelected=-1;
    public List<student> students=new ArrayList<student>();
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //to set content view for that activity
         setContentView(R.layout.popup);
        //end of the setting the layout for the activity

        //this is mechanism to calculate the width and height of the screen
        DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float width=metrics.widthPixels*8/10;
        float  height=metrics.heightPixels*6/10;
        getWindow().setLayout((int)width, (int) height);
        //end of the mechanism

        //the method to populate the list
        populateList();
        //end of the method

        //now creating the recycler view
           recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager
     LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(students);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //end of the recycler view

    }

    //this is event for the ok button
     public void Ok(View view){

     }
    //end of the ok button for the pop activity

    //this is event for the button  named as cancel
    public void Cancel(View view){

    }
    //end of the cancel button event

    //this is method for printing line
     public void PrintLine(String line){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),line,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    //end of the method



    //this method to populate the ArrayList
      public void populateList(){
          String name="Mashhood Qadeer Bhatti";
          String address="Sammundri Faisalabad";
          boolean status=false;
          for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
              students.add(new student(name+"\t"+i,address,status));
          }
      }
    //end of the method


    //this is section for recycler adapter
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<student> values;
                //this is constructor
                public MyAdapter(List<student> myDataset) {
                    values = myDataset;
                }

        //end of the constructor

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.getContext());
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                 holder.name.setText(values.get(position).getName().toString());
                 holder.address.setText(values.get(position).getAddress().toString());
                 holder.status.setSelected(values.get(position).getSelction());
                 if(values.get(position).getSelction()) {
                   holder.layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.im));
                 }
                 else{
                     holder.layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagee));
                 }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        //there will be view holder
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // each data item is just a string in this case
            public TextView name;
            public TextView address;
            public View layout;
            public RadioButton status;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                 super(v);
                 layout = v;
                 name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                 address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
                 status=(RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
                v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      //  mItemSelected = getAdapterPosition();
                        try{
                            PrintLine("The adapter position "+getAdapterPosition());
                            Boolean current_value=values.get(getAdapterPosition()).getSelction();
                            values.get(getAdapterPosition()).setSelction(!current_value);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                       catch(Exception ex){
                        PrintLine("Exception of type"+ex.getMessage());
                       }
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        //end of the view holder


}
//end of that section
}
```